# Variable value is not set

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

According to watch controller.ViewData.ModelState is not null. But after I set its value to modelState variable, I see null as modelState value. It makes me crazy...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried declaring modelState as dynamic instead of "var"?

Comment: @AS-CII, tried - nothing changed